# Optimize TCP connections between two Linux hosts connected by a long lossy channel

Tags: linux, tcp, packetloss

I have two distant hosts. Packet loss is always 19% until the rate exceeds 210 kB/s. The RTT is about 220 ms. The TCP congestion control algorithm is "cubic". "f_rto" is enabled. The actual speed of a TCP connection can only reach 14 kB/s. It's really slow.

Is there any idea about how to optimize TCP connections between the two hosts?

Comment: Have you tried to use smaller packets over the route? It should decrease number of "packets with transmission errors". See `mss` option of `route` command.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Yes, I've tried. But it seems the packet loss is just random.

Comment: Have it affected packet loss ratio and effective transmission speed of single TCP connection? Have you used "full size" (1500 Bytes) packets to measure packet loss?  HOW are the hosts connected? [direct modem link, multi hop link, ....]

Comment: If there any reason why you are seeing 19% packet loss? That is fairly catastrophic for functional TCP.

Answer (score -1):

Use iptables `TEE` target to duplicate packets on both direction. You will have a much more chance to avoid packet loss, but the it costs: the traffic will also doubled.